# The alert function is not working. I used "alert("hello world");" as a external script file

Tags: javascript, html, alert

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script scr ="lecture01.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    this is a basic html page
</body>
```

The alert function is not working. I used "alert("hello world");" as a external script file

Comment: it's *src* not scr in <script scr ="lecture01.js">

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lecture01.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    this is a basic html page
</body>
```

Comment: What did you change in the code and why does it solve the problem?

Comment: when you call an external js file, u should use src and not scr